# записать в файл побайтово

Tags: c++, файлы

Пишу арифметическое кодирование на с++, для работы с большими числами написала свой LongDouble, который представляет число в виде строки. (т.е "0.5936..."). Мне нужно это число записать побайтово в файл. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: если в таком виде хранится число - то может его удобнее как строку записать? если конечно не стоит задача в компактной записи чисел

Comment: @Zhihar, в этом как раз таки и стоит вопрос. Чем меньше весит файл -- тем лучше

Comment: @Annya, а работаете вы с такими числами как? как со строками?

Comment: Приведите ваш код

Comment: @Zhihar. я перегрузила методы + - * (те, что мне были нужны). Структура такая: вектор цифр и экспонента (число, на которое нужно сдвинуть цифры так, чтобы запятая оказалась в нужном месте). А инициализирую конструктором из строки.

Comment: Т.е. Вам нужно записать в бинарный файл само число (а не строку), как обычный `double` например?

Comment: @dIm0n, о каком коде идет речь? я в поисках вариантов, как это можно сделать

Comment: @EOF, строку, так как потом мне эта строка нужна будет и для декодирования

Comment: @Annya о коде LongDouble, который вы хотите записать в файл

Comment: Наверное проще всего сжимать цепочки десятичных цифр (длинные числа), упаковывая в один байт 2 цифры (по 4 бита на цифру. '0' - 0x1, '1' - 0x2, ... '9' - 0xa, '-' - 0xb (думаю, + хранить не нужно)). Двоичный ноль будет терминатором. Когда пишите в файл, то длина вам известна и можно использовать fwrite. Чтение и распаковку делаете в цикле, вызывая fgetc и анализируя прочитанный символ.

Comment: @avp, спасибо большое, идея отличная

Answer (score 0):

Наверное проще всего сжимать цепочки десятичных цифр (длинные числа), упаковывая в один байт 2 цифры (по 4 бита на цифру. '0' - 0x1, '1' - 0x2, ... '9' - 0xa, '-' - 0xb (думаю, + хранить не нужно)). Двоичный ноль будет терминатором. Когда пишите в файл, то длина вам известна и можно использовать fwrite. Чтение и распаковку делаете в цикле, вызывая fgetc и анализируя прочитанный символ.

Comment: @avp, не с того аккаунта ответ запостил